# locking/disabling camera programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios

I've a requirement where I need to programmatically lock/disable the camera as a security aspect. For example, in cases when my device is lost.
I've googled out but couldn't find any solution. Can anyone help me out in providing a solution...

Thanks in Advance
Sudheer

Comment: Why does it matter if someone else gets your phone and uses the camera?  That actually can be helpful as if you have Photostream turned on, you get a GPS hit on the image...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible for an app to do. You would need to disable the camera app via a Mobile Device Management (MDM) solution, which is only available for devices in the enterprise.

As another answerer said, Find My iPhone can also be used, however there is no API for Find My iPhone, where as there is for MDM.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically you can control the camera and other utilities of iPhone in enterprise program. Apple has explicitly mentioned this as a feature of Enterprise program from iOS 3.0 and above.

Please check this link which mention the possibility of this:
http://images.apple.com/ie/iphone/business/docs/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This answer is somewhat correct. You don't have to be enterprise to use the iPhone configuration utility. You just have to apply the configuration profile on the device you wish to manage.

This cannot be done inside a program, you have to explicitly install the profile on the device. If you use Find my iPhone, you can just lock the phone or wipe it remotely without any extra setup.

Comment: He wanted to be able to lock it when the device is lost. You can't install a profile using the config utility if the device is lost :)

Comment: This is how it is planned as of now. When the device is lost and if the user launches the application which we developed, a web service call will be made at the launch which notifies that the device is lost. When this comes as a response we need to wipe off the data. Since there is no direct API to wipe data, we programatcally remove contacts and calendar events as of now. Even planning to lock the camera as well.

Comment: You of course would have to install the profile beforehand, which you can do remotely. Otherwise, this type of activity cannot be done on the iPhone.